# lstlisting vertical offset at beginning of beamer slide

Tags: beamer, lstlisting

After having installed the TeX Live 2018 distribution, I observe a previously unseen vertical offset at the beginning of a list, if the list is the first visible object within a beamer slide.

I can add a negative vertical offset if the listing happens to be at the beginning of a slide but that seems very pedestrian. In addition, we share our slide material in a group of people where not everybody has the same TeX distribution and the differences are uncomfortable.

Does anyone have an idea how to circumvent or even fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % t: top

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]{With Listings}
\begin{lstlisting}
first line (observe the offset to the top)
\end{lstlisting}

second line
\begin{lstlisting}
third line
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: vertical offset image]

Comment: Is `\noindent` sufficient for you? `\begin{frame}[fragile,t]{With Listings}
\noindent
\begin{lstlisting}
first line (observe the offset to the top)
\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: Oh yes, thank you so much. That indeed does the job. I have to insert it before the `\begin{lstlisting}` when it is the first to appear in a beamer frame or in a beamer block. This works accross the different TeX versions that I have seen. That help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you ferahfeza, I consider my problem solved, although I do not really understand the deeper reason for the changed behavior of listings within beamer frames starting from TeX Live 2018.

Comment: @ferahfeza: if you want to elevate your comment to an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\noindent` before `\begin{lstlisting}`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % t: top

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]{With Listings}
\noindent % <--------------------
\begin{lstlisting}
first line (observe the offset to the top)
\end{lstlisting}

second line
\begin{lstlisting}
third line
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```